# Drawing a array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need help with drawing an array. I basically want to draw the array as it looks in the array instead of on 1 line

Here's my array:

```
const int MAP_WD = 5;
const int MAP_HT = 5;


int map[MAP_WD * MAP_HT] = {
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1


};
```

Here's where I'm trying to draw the array:

```
int y, x;
    for (y = 0; y < MAP_HT; ++y)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < MAP_WD; ++x)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "draw"?

Comment: `printf("%d", map[y*5+x])`

Comment: @SamIam why `printf`? :o

Comment: I believe using multidimensional arrays will be more suitable for what you are trying to accomplish here. Of course it is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Try printing a new line at the end of each inner loop.

In the inner loop, print the actual elements.

To get the relevant element, simply use `y*MAP_WD + x`.

Comment: Good answer for such a question - not giving the ultimate solution, but providing useful hints.

Comment: Jco, Thank you for this. I managed to print it but its all on one line, Im using NCurses, How would i make printw go to a newline?

Comment: @Taylor: Why is the first time you've mentioned that crucial detail?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I edited my post a while ago.

Comment: @TaylorStevens: And in precisely _zero_ of your question's revisions is this crucial detail even hinted at.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And if you go check my post you will see it is mentioned..

Comment: @TaylorStevens: No, it isn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Care to try refreshing your page?

Comment: @TaylorStevens: I am quite capable of using my web browser, thank you. I have studied the entire revision history of your question. It does not mention, and has never mentioned, NCurses.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You should have stated the detail you wanted was NCurses, Im using the windows version PDCurses, I thought you was referring to printing new lines, NCurses should make no difference since printing works the same pretty much. Im capable of converting a cout to a printw

Comment: @TaylorStevens: Who cares about printing new lines?!?! The GUI toolkit you're using is _obviously_ critically important. If you're so capable of converting `cout` to `printw`, then let's forget the question that started this whole nonsense off (_"How would i make printw go to a newline?"_) and give you `std::cout << '\n'` to play with. Good day.

Comment: @TaylorStevens If people would know details they want *beforehand* you wouldn't need to state them. Unfortunately, humans are not telepaths so instead of trying to teach people how to use their Web Browsers consider the advice given here and do put some effort and thought in your questions next time.

Comment: Sorry @TaylorStevens, I don't really have experience with NCurses. As others have said, you didn't really specify... Also tone it down a bit everyone, no need to fight each other...